# The "transfer NFT" function works smoothly on occasions, yet occasionally fails with transactions being reverted to their initial state

Tags: ethers.js, nft, custom-errors

I am using OpenZeppelin for minting and transfering the nft's.I tried increasing the gas fee but the transaction just gets stuck . Using etherJs for interacting with the contract

Code For this :-

```
function approveTransfer(address[] memory to, uint256 tokenId) public {

// Ensure that the caller is the owner of the token

require(
ownerOf(tokenId) == msg.sender,
"You are not the owner of this token"
 );

 // Approve the transfer

for (uint256 i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
  approve(to[i], tokenId);
  }

}


    function transferNFT(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) public {

    // Ensure that the caller is approved to transfer the token

    // Transfer the token

    safeTransferFrom(from, to, tokenId);

   }
```

This is the way i am calling the transaction from react :-

```
    const transaction = await 
    contract_nft.transferNFT(tdata.donor_id.meta_address , 
    tdata.reciever_id.meta_address , nftId );
          const toastId = toast.info('Transaction in Progress', { autoClose: 
    false });
    await transaction.wait();
```

Error :-
MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted ► (code: -32603, message: 'execution reverted', : (4)
VM200:1
Error: execution reverted (unknown custom error) (action="estimateGas", data="0x177e802f0000000000000000000000009f9f6c7c5984524f2674b24ebf2471c9cd4af2940000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006", reason=null, transaction={ "data": "Ox69e9cae100000000000000000000000000e124d8eeae92b5989103d3b47dalfefd0193a40000000000000000000000008d6338c47bb8bad6cc677b3f2918a83b4ee1443d0000000000000000000 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006", "from": "Ox9f9f6c7c5984524f2674B24eBf2471C9cD4AF294", "to": "Ox072d27C4C80002c7DB5e509d33Edb5f1C0f4ad59" }, invocation=null, revert=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=6.8.1) at makeError (errors.ts:694:1) at getBuiltinCallException (abi—coder.ts:118:1) at AbiCoder.getBuiltinCallException (abi—coder.ts:230:1) at BrowserProvider.getRpcError (provider—jsonrpc.ts:906:1) at BrowserProvider.getRpcError (provider—browser.ts:107:1) at provider—jsonrpc.ts:526:1
TimeLine.jsx:323